# Why Clang does not optimize returning of std::string by empty "" constant?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, optimization, clang

```
#include <string>

std::string foo1()
{
    return "";
}

std::string foo2()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    const std::string& test1 = foo1();
    const std::string& test2 = foo2();

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/ifgNbl

Clang 3.8 with `-O3` made this:

```
foo1():                               # @foo1()
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     rbx, rdi
        lea     rdx, [rsp + 8]
        mov     esi, .L.str
        call    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        ret

foo2():                               # @foo2()
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage+24
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

But GCC made this (i.e. the same code):

```
foo1[abi:cxx11]():
        lea     rdx, [rdi+16]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+16], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        ret
foo2[abi:cxx11]():
        lea     rdx, [rdi+16]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+16], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        ret
```

Why Clang even in the last version does not optimize return of `""`? Is there any reason for this in the standard, or they forgot about it?

Comment: Well, isn't setting `size` to zero sufficient?

Comment: Have you looked at the library implementation? There might be special cases triggered for gcc. Also did you explicitly use the same std version on both? Which std library is clang and gcc using. Is it the same?